# AngularJS Directive Template URL Requires Leading Slash, Breaks Tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner

```
'use strict';

directives.directive('primaryClient', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    templateUrl: 'views/directives/primary-client.html',
    scope: {
      'client': '='
    }
  };
});
```

I've got a simple directive that just replaces an element with the contents of a template file. As shown above, it's broken. The error in Chrome is `Error: Unexpected request: GET views/directives/primary-client.html`. Adding a leading slash (i.e. `/views/directives/primary-client.html`) fixes the problem.

HOWEVER

In my tests, I am absolutely unable to get it working WITH the leading slash. I get the file loaded and passing the test when I omit the leading slash, but that of course breaks the actual functionality.

I can share more code from the tests if needed, but examples of tests with loaded templates all seem to show the directive omitting the leading slash. I've got `<base href="/">` set in index.html. Is there something I'm doing wrong that's forcing the leading slash?

Comment: Can you post your test code? Are you using httpBackend to mock up the template response?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34301958/283366

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently with relative paths and tests.  In my directives I always have the leading slash:

```
templateUrl: '/dist/js/templates/my-template.html'
```

This works fine in my app, but then when I run tests I get the `Unexpected request: GET` error.

I was able to fix this using the [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor) and by playing around with relative versus non-relative filepaths until it was working.

Basically, in my karma config, for preprocessors I have (notice no slash before public):

```
preprocessors: {
        'public/js/templates/**/*.html': ['ng-html2js']
    },
```

In my file list in my karma config I have (again, no slash before public):

```
files: [
        'public/js/templates/**/*.html'
    ],
```

Then I set up the preprocessor in my karma config as follows (notice the slash before dist, that's the important part)

```
ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
        stripPrefix: 'public',
        prependPrefix: '/dist',
        moduleName: 'dir-templates'
    }
```

This means that the preprocessor will take my template file at `public/js/templates/my-template.html` and put it in the cache under `/dist/js/templates/my-template.html`

Then in my actual test I import the special module `dir-templates`, as defined under the moduleName for the preprocessor above, like so:

```
beforeEach(
    module('app')
);

beforeEach(
    module('dir-templates')
);
```

And everything works!