# karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor not creating modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

Attempting to use the karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor. Karma has been finding all of my other stuff (javascript) fine, but when it comes to this html preprocessor it can't seem to find and generate a module from it.

Check out my options object below. As you can see, I've added a pattern to the files attribute and I'm using the generic name 'foo' for the module. In the test, karma throws an error whenever I try to call `module('foo');`
I really want to be able to use this so I don't have to hardcode templates into my unit tests or some other wacky solution.

```
    var options = {
        files: [].concat(
            bowerFiles,
            config.specHelpers,
            clientApp + '**/*.module.js',
            clientApp + '**/*.js',
            clientApp + '**/*.html',
            '*.html',
            temp + config.templateCache.file,
            config.serverIntegrationSpecs
            ),
        exclude: [],
        coverage: {
            dir: report + 'coverage',
            reporters: [
                // reporters not supporting the `file` property
                { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
                { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' },
                { type: 'text-summary' } //, subdir: '.', file: 'text-summary.txt'}
            ]
        },
        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            // strip this from the file path
            // stripPrefix: clientApp,
            moduleName: 'foo'
        },
        preprocessors: {}
    };
    options.preprocessors[clientApp + '**/*.html'] = ['ng-html2js'];
    options.preprocessors[clientApp + '**/!(*.spec)+(.js)'] = ['coverage'];
    return options;
}
```

Comment: Your `preprocessors` key `'*.html'` might not be matching anything in `clientApp + '**/*.html'`. Try using the same pattern or even just `'**/*.html'`?

Comment: You're right, I actually changed it to that at exactly the same time as you commented, but that didn't seem to fix it. I've updated my original post to show what the options object looks like now.

Comment: Do the paths in your `templateUrl` properties include whatever `clientApp` is? For example, say `clientApp = 'myApp/src'`, are your `templateUrl` properties like `'myApp/src/path/to/template.html'`?

Comment: clientApp = "./src/client/app/"
templateUrl: "src/client/app/orders/'

but i've tried it without clientApp as well...

Comment: If you fire up Karma using a real browser (not Phantom), you can view the source of the page and look at the included script files. Have a look for your templates and the path / keys used to add them to `$templateCache`. Do they match the values in `templateUrl`?

Comment: I've never used it outside of phantomJS, how can I do that?

Comment: Typically just with the `browsers` property and the right launcher. The angular-seed project uses Chrome as an example ~ See https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/package.json and https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/karma.conf.js

Comment: Ok, can't try that right now but I will give it a shot later.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't necessarily answer your question and if more information comes to light, I'll add to this answer but I've found this strategy works well...

I find that the HTML template of a directive, route or state (if using *ui-router*) shouldn't come into play when unit testing. Unit testing is about testing the interface to your component; its publicly available methods and properties. Testing the interactions with the HTML document is really in the realm of end-to-end testing with something like Protractor.

With that in mind, here's how I prevent Karma from attempting to load template files during testing.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('module.name.of.the.testable.component');

    inject(function($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put('path/to/template/as/it/appears/in/your/component.html',
            '<div></div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: That's cool, except what if my template is relatively large (it's not huge, but huge enough that it's going to be annoying to have in the code) and you don't want to bother with maintaining the code in two different places?

Comment: @z0d14c I actually meant to literally use `'<div></div>'` as the `$templateCache` entry. When unit testing, the template really shouldn't matter. It's just to stop Karma attempting to load the HTML file.

Comment: well if I want to test a property of the template (like that it exists), uh, shouldn't it matter or no?

Comment: @z0d14c like what? You can test properties assigned to the scope or controller easy enough and if you're looking for DOM manipulation in a directive, you can always spy on (assuming Jasmine) the `element` methods